# Fitting an image as a border to a div of any size

Tags: html, css, image, border

I have seen several websites built with Wix that use borders that are images. The images themselves are massive and I have tried a few techniques but I cannot figure out for the life of me how they manage it. This is one of the images: http://bit.ly/1lZfHRn

I have tried placing an outside div around the content but using padding and margins I cannot get it to work correctly.

When viewed on a Wix site the border literally fits perfectly, when resized the image of course retains it's aspect ratio and the amount of transparency. However, Wix have managed to bring the border out more and lower the amount of transparency. I really do not understand how they managed this, especially on an image of about 192 x 192 while using the exact same image I linked.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I would really appreciate knowing the workings behind how such a thing works!

Comment: Could you post a link to one of those Wix site?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1fIEtS6 - There is a link to one of the wix sites. I used FireBug to remove the image and then right-click > view background image. Shows the actual size.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ePn5k/2/) ?

Choose a background, overlay an image, and ajust the image and background so they fit as you see fit.

CSS

```
.testme {
    width: 550px;
    height: 400px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/YTPgXWG.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 550px 320px;
    padding: 20px;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Essentially yes, except the size of the initial image is nearly 2000px sq. And yet they bring the border up on that as if it was already 196px sq, pretty much eliminating most of the center transparency.

Comment: You can change the size of the image to anything you want. You could also grab that image, make the whole center black, and save it as a jpg or png - giving you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: I'm sure I've just edited the FIDDLE so that it know uses the reflected image and the border is very clearly still not quite what I am looking to achieve as is portrayed in the link I posted here: http://bit.ly/1fIEtS6